# iOS POST only working sometimes

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
NSString *post = @"i hope this gets there";

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [post length]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.oneoftwosites.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:nil];

//potential response
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

//convert response so that it can be LOG'd
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"RETURN: %@", returnString);
```

I have tested it with 2 different websites: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/cgi-bin/mycgi.pl and http://instagraph.me/post, by substituting those urls in for `http://www.oneoftwosites.com`.  For some reason, it only works with the first website (which is written in perl), and not with the second (which is written in .php).

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be?  It seems dumb that it would only work sometimes, but I don't really have any idea why it doesn't work for the second website (I haven't seen the code but I did see some sample output).

---

EDIT:  I added

`[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];` and tried a couple different types but still no luck

Comment: You might try setting the HTTP Host header? That has been a problem I have had in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of POST data does Instagraph expect? Chances are, it's some kind of structured data, like a URL encoded form, or XML, or JSON. Your string is neither of those. So provide a `Content-Type`, and format your POST data accordingly. Maybe you'll get better luck then.

EDIT: Your second site is Instagraph. It's a public website. It probably has a documented API - what fields and values should there be in a POST. Is the POST data that you're sending up to that spec? So far, I don't think so. If you sending dummy, test data - why are you expecting it to work? What sensible effect are you expecting?

The line "i hope this gets there" does not, by the way, constitute a valid data block of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 0):

The post length should come from postData

```
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
```